# SilverStripe 3: UserForms integrate with MailChimp?

Tags: php, module, mailchimp, silverstripe, mailing-list

Has anyone managed to use the very hand UserForms module: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-userforms and extended it to include a checkbox (or similar) allowing users to be optionally added to a MailChimp mailing list?
http://www.mailchimp.com

The developer says:

> "Simply use the DataExtension on SubmittedForm and hook into
>   updateAfterProcess to perform any actions on after submission."

but this is out of my knowledge range...

Comment: Well I'm not actually sure exactly how to go about this. Looking at the MailChimp API docs it lists some PHP examples https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/#php. This ones looks interesting as it only needs to be 'simple' - adding the email to the list. https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/ but how and where to add it I need help / guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use userforms for this? Creating a form in PHP isn't that difficult with silverstripe, and you can commit your form to git, so you have it out of the box where you install it. 
There are already some modules for SS which integrate mailchimp, have you seen them? Look here: http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons?search=mailchimp

Comment: The main reason is I want a contact form first with optional subscribe. You can simply use the forms from Mailchimp for subscription only and it appears the all these add ons create subscription forms rather than optional subscription (I may be wrong). Flexiform looks good and has the MailChimp extension but after installing it it doesn't give me the Submissions tab, I've not worked out how to get this to work yet. So I thought I'd try UserForms again..

Comment: I had something like that up but not with Mailchimp and sstr 2.4. I'll see if I can dig this up, but I'll need some time to do so. @wmk UserForms is often used and if you can have Checkboxes for all your Newsletter-Channels in the Form it's an easy way to get Subscribers.

Comment: Thanks @munomono, UserForms is very popular and it would be great to have this functionality. I just installed SilverChimp https://github.com/zucchi/SilverChimp which is great but again not a contact form...

Answer (score 1):

basically working but needs a lot more love - just go ahead and PR :)
https://github.com/lerni/EditableMailchimpSubscriptionField

Comment: I have an error trying to use this... :( after adding it and the mail chimp-api and uncommenting and adding my API key, I do a dev/build and the form field appears as NewsletterSignup on the form, clicking "Add" gives me: "An error occured while fetching data from the server Please try again later." then: "Internal server error" I've got it in DEV mode but nothing else is being shown.. refreshing the page gives me a white screen, and no error messages.. Have I missed something?

Comment: It's likely possible that it erros out of the box :) I can imagine it'll fail if no list, fields or group is set up in MC. I'll put this a bit more in shape as time permits but just trying set up those things in MC could make it probable work...

Comment: Ahh ok.. Well I do have a list in MC, where exactly do I need to add the fields to in MC and which ones? They need to match the userform or just the editablemailchimpsubscriptionfield? thanks!

Comment: Can we keep discussion on Github? https://github.com/lerni/EditableMailchimpSubscriptionField/issues/3